# How to access iphone Memory card (SDcard) programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, xamarin.ios

I want to access sdcard of iphone, I have some question regarding this.

1. by searching little bit i think iphone donot support sdcard ? if it support SDcard then kindly tell how we access iphone expanded memory what is path path of external storage of iphone. for example as in android we can access sdcard directory by

   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();    ( return path to sdcard in android )
2. how to see sdcard contents in emulator of like in eclipse we can see android's SDcard folder in Forlder explorer any thing like this is in iphone?
3. how to get list of sdcard contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no SD card.

Applications may only access their own sandbox Documents and cache folders. If you need to transfer files, you have three options:

1. E-mail.
2. iTunes File Sharing
3. iCloud

Comment: ok,can you tell me where iphone store audio ,video content and can we access these content through code.for example i want to take backup of these files on ftp programitically not using any other  application.

Comment: You missed the point of Mr. Ramin's answer: You can't access audio and video content on the device because it's outside the application's sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

hello salman Roy First of all i want to tell you that there is no external sdcard like android in the iphone or ipad.it is all sandbox environment.And one more thing for the iphone development there is no emulator its a simulator.